# Updates attributes from an empty form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want users to click a button to publish an event in my publish page.

**views/events/publish.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @event do |p| %>       
   <%= p.submit "Yes publish my event now" %> | 
   <%= link_to "Cancel", events_path %>
<% end %>
```

Users can get to the publish page from my index page

**views/events/index.html.erb**

```
<% for event in @events %>
   <%= link_to "Publish", publish_path(:id => event) %>
<% end %>
```

Publish_path has been define in routes to be in the Events Controller

**routes.rb**

```
match 'publish' => 'events#publish', :as => :publish
```

Here is my event controller

**events_controller.rb**

```
def publish
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

When I added code (see below) to update the event model in my publish action, the controller will update the attributes but when the user clicks on the Publish link in my index.

With this code users can't see my publish page when they click on the publish link in index. Instead they will be sent back to the index page but all the attributes are updated.

```
def publish
   @event = Event.find(params[:id])
   if @event.update_attributes(:published_at => DateTime.now, :publish => true)
     flash[:success] = "Your event has been publish"
     redirect_to events_path
   end
end
```

Question is, How to I get the user from Index page -> Publish page -> click submit -> update the attributes -> return back to Index page with flash message?

Comment: +1 for detail, but can you explain the problem a little more? What's happening that you don't want to happen?

Comment: What do you mean by index page? The `index` action of your `EventsController`? Are you displaying the flash on that page?

Comment: What is currently happening is Index Page -> click link to go to Publish Page -> attributes updated -> Index Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess you are trying to achieve the following work flow, `Index page -> Publish page -> click submit -> update the attributes -> return back to Index page with flash message`

We cannot achieve both using a single action, so add one more action

**events_controller**

```
# Will take user to confirm page, where we display the form with "Yes publish now" and "cancel" button
def confirm_publish
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
end

# When user clicks the "yes publish now" button, request should come here and perform the same.
def publish
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  if @event.update_attributes(:published_at => DateTime.now, :publish => true)
    flash[:success] = "Your event has been publish"
    redirect_to events_path
  end
end
```

Correspondingly we need to modify the views and routes.

Comment: In my **confirm_publish.html.erb** I added `<%= form_for @event, url => {:action => 'publish'}, do |p| %>`. But then it says `No route matches {:action=>"publish", :controller=>"events"}` I already have `resources :events` in my **routes.rb**. What am I missing?